# Is ThreadPool QueueUserWorkItem best option for handling event?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, bluetooth

I have a WinForms application that has value change event coming from ble device.
The event can be hit from more than one device also one device can send a notification to event in every 4 secs. averagely so I am adding device data to a queue to use data after that. This method works but after a while stops working. Is `ThreadPool` the best option to handle this kind of situation?

```
protected void Characteristic_ValueChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x)=>
        {

            GattCharacteristic characteristic = sender;
            string data = GetByteData(characteristic.Service.Device.BluetoothAddress).Result;
            queue.Enqueue(new EventDataModel { IOData = characteristic, IOKey = characteristic.Service.Device.BluetoothAddress.ToString() });

        });

    }
```

Comment: _This method working but after a while stops working_ - this looks like a bug.

Comment: @t3chb0t maybe device software can cause this situation but all i want to do is seperating each hit and its data.

Answer (score 6):

Without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to know what's going on but this is always* bad:

```
string data = GetByteData(characteristic.Service.Device.BluetoothAddress).Result;
```

* as long as `GetByteData` is `async` and returning a `Task<string>`

You should queue an `async` delegate instead:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async x =>
    {
        GattCharacteristic characteristic = sender;
        string data = await GetByteData(characteristic.Service.Device.BluetoothAddress).ConfigureAwait(false);
        queue.Enqueue(new EventDataModel { IOData = characteristic, IOKey = characteristic.Service.Device.BluetoothAddress.ToString() });
    });
```

Note the use of `await` with `ConfigureAwait(false)`. See [Stephen Cleary's blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) to learn more about why blocking on async code is such a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i need long time testing but its working without problem up to now. Thanks thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can hit the ThreadPool limit if there are lots of devices. Add the following check:

```
protected void Characteristic_ValueChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (!ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x)=>
        {
            GattCharacteristic characteristic = sender;
            string data = GetByteData(characteristic.Service.Device.BluetoothAddress).Result;
            !queue.Enqueue(new EventDataModel { IOData = characteristic, IOKey = characteristic.Service.Device.BluetoothAddress.ToString(); 
        })
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("There are not enough threads to process the request");
        };
    }
```

Comment: Up vote then? :)

Comment: it never throws exception :(